# How to avoid certain files while merging with another branch in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches A and B in gitlab. I made changes in java code as well as changes in web.xml in  branch B. Now I want to merge it with branch A.  I want that while merging all java code get merged but web.xml doesn't get merged. Both branches retains their own lines of code. How to achieve this?

Suppose in Branch A  web.xml lines of code is 
 This is Branch A code.

Suppose in Branch B  web.xml lines of code is 
 This is Branch B code.

After merging, I want this to be retained.

Right now while merging, branch A web.xml gets overrriden with branch B.

Can anyone help me on this.

I tried using gitattributes. But i think its not working for me or I am proceeding the wrong way.

folder structure for the project is 
All in root directory
entity
controller
pom.xml
web.xml

Expected is to not merge the xml files in two branches. I want to retain their code in both.

Comment: `I want to retain their code in both.` ... what do you mean by this?  After the merge, there can only be one version of `web.xml`.  _Which_ version of `web.xml` do you want?

Comment: I want Both the branches retain their own codes. If branch A has code like "This is Branch A" and Branch B has code like "This is Branch B". So after merge, It should not change. I want to ignore this file while merge. How can I achieve that

Comment: How have you tried with gitattributes so far?

Comment: I  Added  .gitattributes file at the root level of repository.
 I added a line of code in branch B as 
web.xml merge=ours
Then did merge request but it stills changes branch A web.xml
Do I need to add in both branches?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have done `git merge [...]` you can leave certain files as you had them before in your branch. E.g.:

```
git merge --no-commit origin/feature_branch
git checkout HEAD web.xml
git add web.xml
git commit
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you get the file out of the index (with the mixed reset) at step two? I would have done the same without this step. What did I miss?

Comment: Because a assume there were no conflicts in `web.xml` file. Therefore the changes introduced by the merge are already staged and the `git checkout --ours web.xml` doesn't work. If there were merge conflicts, then you can omit that step.

Comment: Ok. No need to reset. You can also do `git checkout HEAD --ours web.xml` in this case. I change it. So it's more simple. Actually no need for the `--ours` either.

Comment: I am not able to do . Firstly I cloned a project from master. Then, I created one new branch as dev(copy of master) in gitlab. I made some changes there in java code and web.xml. Now, I am trying to merge it with master from gitbash. I am not able to follow the  correct steps.

Can someone help me stepwise using gitbash

Comment: I guess you did the changes in your branch doing `git add .` and `git commit`. Maybe you pushed them with `git push`. To merge them to master branch, you have to checkout master and merge by doing `git checkout master` and the steps I wrote in the answer. It asumes you pushed the changes on feature branch to remote, if you didn’t, omit `origin/`

Comment: git merge --no-commit origin/feature_branch

feature_branch means source branch right? like I have to merge from dev to master,so feature branch will be dev here in this case

Comment: Yes, that’s it, in your case it would be `dev`